# Does ansible have a convention for where to look for roles?

Tags: ansible

It appears that Ansible has a lot of conventions, i.e. for where to look for `host_vars` and for certain other things. I wonder if there is a simpler way to run an ansible task.

Currently I do this.
`ansible-playbook ./roles/neo4j/tasks/create.yml`

But I wonder if there is a more terse way of doing this. 
i.e.

`ansible-playbook neo4j/create`

This might seem simple but I feel like the method I am currently using is too verbose and there must be a better way.

My directory structure looks like this [image: directory-structure]

Comment: Why are you running a role directly with ansible-playbook instead of using it to run a play? It isn't really designed for the former.

Comment: I'm still learning :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @tedder42 mentioned in a comment, you should use a playbook instead of calling ansible-**playbook** with roles. I didn't even know this was possible. Maybe you got something wrong in the role as well and have the content of the playbook in the roles task file instead. Because I would expect Ansible to not know on which hosts to run the role.

Ansible will look for roles relative to your playbook. So if your playbook would be saved on the same level as your inventory file and had content like this it would work:

```
---

- name: Do something
  hosts: all
  roles:
     - neo4j
...
```

The only thing you would need to change is the name of the tasks file though. (`create.yml`) Ansible expects the name of the main yaml file to be `main.yml`.

Also see http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_roles.html#roles